# Not supported in SOAP 1.1

Tags: web-services, soap, axis

I have a strange problem with my SOAP WS.

```
2015-09-03 18:08:28.363 ERROR <main> {AWT-EventQueue-1} [XPosFunction]     javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Not supported in SOAP 1.1
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Not supported in SOAP 1.1
at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:165)
at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:102)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:236)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:206)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:103)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy207.calculateTax70(Unknown Source)
```

It is quite strange because it was working well and now it isnt... I recognizede that the problem can be in libraries in project, but I dont know wich one could cause this. Do someone have the same or similar experience?

I am using this

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And AXIS as well.

Thanks a lot for any response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this. I only have used version 2.2.8 of jaxws-rt library.